# Open the xx.html file based on drop down menu from Navigation bar, code is written in Django-Python

Tags: javascript, python, django

1. The code is written in Django-Python. The project is created using the models in Django and shown in navigation as dropdown menu.
2. The drop-down menu is shown using the Django-HTML as shown in following way:

This code works well for dropdown menu. but I want to open the different project url based on click.

I am not sure exactly how to assign id and use javascript to code do onclick bsed html loading !!

I have tried some javascript code, but I am novice.. so If I put here.. it would be more confusing.

```
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="navbarDropdown">
    {% if project_records %}
    {% for p in project_records %}
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item"> {{ p.pName }} </a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </div>
```

I expect that projectB.html will be loaded if click projectB in dropdown menu in navigation bar.

Comment: Do you even need JS for this? Just put the target URL in the `href` attribute, replacing the "#".

Comment: Add the target URL in `href` as `<a href="http://someurl/{{p.pName}}" class="dropdown-item"> {{ p.pName }} </a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `href` attribute in anchor tag appropriately. Assuming `http://someurl/` is the `prefix` and the project name is the `suffix` of your project URLs, you may form the target URL in a variable and use it. Here is your modified code:

```
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="navbarDropdown">
    {% if project_records %}
    {% for p in project_records %}
    {% with project_url="http://someurl"|add:p.pName %}
    <a href={{project_url}} class="dropdown-item"> {{ p.pName }} </a>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot  Chris & Fiveelements !!  The problem is resolved as following: 1) Created the view for each projectA, projectB and so on. 2) Added in URLS.py 3) used the syntax as href="{{ p.pName }}" ..  as the view name match with p.pName it opened successfully.   Really a great help :)